# Rails development errors in production with Unicorn,Nginx

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

We've had several instances of uses reporting errors with our site where they saw Rails' development type error page - they helpfully sent screenshots.

In all instances, the error itself wasn't a problem to solve, but I've never been able to reproduce an error that would show the development error page. For example, In one case it was a template error "no method '<' for nil" so I set up a secret route that would duplicate that error, but this just showed the contents of 500.html when I tried it.

I've confirmed that all app servers are running in production mode.

The version of Rails is 3.1.10 and its running on Nginx 0.7.65. 
There's a similar post here on SO but its related to Phusion Passenger.

Sorry there's not much information to go on here.

Update:
This always happens with SSL
If I access one of the app servers directly by editing my hosts file, I get the proper 500.html, but I get the development type error when viewing normally (via load balancer).

Here's my nginx config: gist.github.com/davidnorth/5063830

Comment: I've found that this is only happening in SSL, and I am able to reproduce consisitently by using SSL with my test error page.

However its not the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10435978/error-messages-showing-in-production-ruby-on-rails-3-1-nginx-unicorn - I have:

  location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

for both http and https

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using this workaround in an initialiser. This has no effect in development.

```
class ActionDispatch::Request
 def local?
   false
 end
end
```